Pointwise convergence of $f_n(x)=\frac{x}{n}e^{-\frac{x}{n}}$
I am currently studying real analysis at university, and I am having some trouble with a problem about pointwise convergence.
In this problem, I need to show the pointwise convergence of the function $\frac{x}{n}e^{-\frac{x}{n}}$ on $[0, \infty)$, and I became curious whether my approach is correct.
I would appreciate it if you could help me with these questions:

Is it valid to evaluate convergence in this way?
$
\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x}{n}e^{-\frac{x}{n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x}{n} \times \lim_{n\to\infty}e^{-\frac{x}{n}}=0
$
I feel like this approach might not be correct, but I'm not sure why. Could you let me know if this is valid or, if not, explain why?
(The textbook suggests showing convergence using the maximum of the function, but I couldn't figure out how to use that in this case.)

If $f_n(x)$ is defined on a closed interval, such as $[0, \alpha]$ for $\alpha \in (0, \infty)$, would the result change?


I haven't been learning for long, so any guidance or hints would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Which textbook do you use? I guess the hint in the book might refer to uniform convergence. When you want to show pointwise convergence, then $x$ is fixed as $n$ goes to infinity. Then your use of limit calculus is correct.  However when you can prove uniform convergence, you already have shown pointwise convergence. For that you would just evaluate $f_n'(x)=0$ and evaluate the maximum.

Thank you for your comment! I'm using "Introduction to Real Analysis, third edition" of Manfred Stoll. And this problem is from the chapter on pointwise convergence, which comes before the chapter on uniform convergence. In fact, I don't understand why the textbook is asking about the convergence on the interval $[0, \alpha]$. TT


Your approach is technically correct, but be careful when using the fact that the limit of a product is the product of the limits. Your book probably suggests using the fact that $|e^{-\frac{x}{n}}| \leq 1$ for all $x \geq 0$. Then you can bound the functions $f_n$ by $\frac{x}{n}$, and from this, it's easy to conclude.

Yes, it's the same in the intervals $[0, \alpha]$, but in this case, we can obtain an improvement: note in (1) that $\frac{x}{n}$ can be made as small as you want by taking large $n$, independent of the value of $x$. This means that in this case, you have uniform convergence.



Oh, I see your point! So, I guess the problem was meant to introduce the idea of uniform convergence. Thank you! That was really helpful.
